# How Kosher are picture heavy answers?

Tags: discussion

A few weeks ago [I asked a question and got some excellent responses](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/2351/smart-deadbolt-without-motor-read-only-access). Based on those responses I did some more research and worked out a solution. That said, the responses are incomplete -- There was a lot of extra research involved. I have pictures of the process and would like to post them here, but that's a lot of pictures -- I don't know if picture heavy posts are really kosher.

I considered posting to an Imgur album, and just linking it, but I also know external links are not a great idea due to dead linking.

What would be the preferable solution here?

Answer (score 5):

You should definitely share your solution if you want to do so – I really appreciate it when we hear how questions actually get solved.

Whether you should embed all the images in the post depends on exactly how many images there are. If there are more than about 5 or 6, and it's probably going to take up a lot of vertical space on a page, embedding them all probably isn't so practical. There are a few options you have:

1. Just use an Imgur album. While we generally do discourage **link-only** answers, it doesn't sound like your post would be considered low-quality in that respect, since you'll probably have a little commentary to add in your post too.  If you're concerned about the link going dead, there's an alternative...
2. Upload images using the Stack Exchange image uploader, and convert the image markup to a link. Stack Exchange has dedicated Imgur hosting on `i.stack.imgur.com`, where images will **never** be automatically deleted. Once uploaded there, it doesn't actually matter whether you just link to the image or actually embed it  into your post. If embedding into the post is impractical, just change the image markup inserted automatically:

   ```
   ![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXAMPLE)
   ```

   into link markup:

   ```
   [enter link description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EXAMPLE)
   ```

   Just by deleting the `!` and adding a link description.

Just do whatever's easiest – an Imgur album is probably a lot easier, but doesn't have the guarantees of lasting forever, unlike the Stack Imgur.

I'm looking forward to hearing your solution!

Answer (score 3):

Pictures are great when they supplement the text. If you have diagrams explaining the process, then by all means please post them.

There's no problem to having many pictures in an answer if they're relevant. For example, [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/150098/did-the-minor-houses-in-game-of-thrones-ever-have-any-major-power/165731#165731) is the answer on Science Fiction and Fantasy with the largest number of images (43) — all the images are relevant, if peripheral. [This question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/147798/does-this-cut-material-from-rogue-one-still-appear-in-the-novelisation) has even more (this one may be a tad over the top). (Courtesy of [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/772702/posts-with-the-most-images) — warning, it's expensive, it probably won't work on the biggest sites.) Probably closest to your use case: [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/129102/in-the-walking-dead-how-do-the-survivors-get-access-to-clean-water/129158#129158), where the illustrations contribute directly to the answer.

Having pictures *instead of text* would be another matter — it's unavoidable on Stack Exchange when you want to draw diagrams, but keep in mind that text in pictures is not searchable and is not accessible to blind people.

Whatever you do, make sure that the answer will still be there in a few years time. This means: **use only resources that are hosted by Stack Exchange** (or on behalf of SE). Stack Exchange has a contract with Imgur. If you upload an image through the editor tool (“Image” icon or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> shortcut), it's uploaded to `i.stack.imgur.com`, not to the regular Imgur servers. Images on Stack Exchange's Imgur server never expire, unlike regular Imgur images which *have* been known to expire even when their author hadn't configured them to expire. It's even possible that Stack Exchange may one day forbid inline images that aren't hosted on this server.

If you feel that the images are taking too much space, then you can link to them. Use the regular upload tool, then change the `![][42]` link to `[link text][42]`.